# Group chat communication in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have did the main requirement which is to create a group chat using multiple members using threads; however, i have reached a part where i need to send old messages for members who have entered the group late, they need to receive all the previous messages as well as the messages that are being send now.

i managed to create members of a group using the same address and port, i duplicated the class and changed each configuration with different id to distinguish between the members. I also managed to create the communication between them using a thread that sends messages from each member.

My code is based on threads, so this is my thread class to send messages:

```
public SendMessagesThread (MulticastSocket groupSocket, InetAddress groupAddress, String ID, int numMsgs) {
        this.groupSocket = groupSocket;
        this.groupAddress = groupAddress;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.numMsgs = numMsgs;
        this.start();
 }

public void run(){
    try {                         
        System.out.println("Transmitting new messages to the group: ");
        for ( int i = 1; i <= numMsgs ; i++ ) {
                String m = new String ("MSG" + ID + i); 
                DatagramPacket msgOut = new DatagramPacket(m.getBytes(), m.length(), groupAddress, groupSocket.getLocalPort());
                groupSocket.send(msgOut);
```

I also have a memberThread class to create the member and run the previous thread. I have also created another thread to store the messages of each member, this is the thread:

```
MulticastSocket groupSocket;
    InetAddress groupAddress;
    int numMsgs;
    String ID;
    public storeMessagesThread (MulticastSocket groupSocket, InetAddress groupAddress, String ID, int numMsgs) {
            this.groupSocket = groupSocket;
            this.groupAddress = groupAddress;
            this.ID = ID;
            this.numMsgs = numMsgs;
            this.start();
     }

    public void run(){
        try {   
            //MulticastSocket s =null;
            System.out.println("storing messages of member "+ID);  //where should i store the data??
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];     // to get the message
            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
            for ( int i = 1; i <= numMsgs ; i++ ) {
                DatagramPacket msgIn = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);

                groupSocket.receive(msgIn);
                String newmsg = new String(msgIn.getData(), 0, msgIn.getLength());
                String msg = newmsg;
                data.add(msg);
            }

            oldMessages storing = new oldMessages(data);
```

What i struggle to accomplish here, is how can i create another thread to send the old messages of the group members to the newly added members. The result i went to achieve is for the new members of the group to receive the old messages that has been sent before they joined; however, in my case, the new members of the group doesn't receive the old messages, only the new ones.

Comment: A lot of code is missing and i don't think we can help you if you don't show us more code.

Comment: Also i think you should add more oop to your project to make things a lot easier